# USB 3.0 Issues with Windows7

Tags: usb, cdc

Please see the Equipment Used

```
Atmel USB CDC (ACM) communicating device
HP ProBook Laptop(6470b) with 2 USB 3.0 & 1 USB 2.0 ports
32bit - Windows 7 Professional edition.
USB 2.0 (Type B)Cable
```

I am having trouble when I am connecting the CDC device to USB 3.0 Port.
The Error code is 10 "This Device cannot start"

When I either restart the laptop or the CDC device The device is working properly. But
again if I unplug & plug the USB cable the error is reproduced.
The device is working Fine on USB 2.0 Port ,only  issue with USB 3.0 port.
On Windows 8, I do not have any issue. Only Problem with windows 7, USB 3.0 Ports.

Could you Please help me in this issue.

Driver Details : usbser.sys , mdmcpq.inf

Is there any other driver through which I can access a USB CDC device.

> INF File settings:
>      ====================
>
> [Version]
>      DriverVer =04/02/2012,3.00
>     Signature = "$CHICAGO$" 
>      Class = Modem 
>      ClassGuid = {XYZ-XYZ-XYZ-XYZ} 
>      Provider = %Mfg%
>      CatalogFile = USBXYZ.cat
>
> [Manufacturer] 
>      %MG% = XYZ_Devices,NTx86,NTamd64,NTia64
>
> [ControlFlags]
>      ExcludeFromSelect=*
>
> [DestinationDirs]
>      DefaultDestDir = 12
>
> [XYZ_Devices.NTx86] 
>      %XYZ% = XYZ_Install,USB\VID_16DE&PID_0010
>      %XYZ% = XYZ_Install,USB\VID_16DE&PID_0012
>      [XYZ_Devices.NTamd64] 
>      %XYZ% = XYZ_Install,USB\VID_16DE&PID_0010
>      %XYZ% = XYZ_Install,USB\VID_16DE&PID_0012
>      [XYZ_Devices.NTia64] 
>      %XYZ% = XYZ_Install,USB\VID_16DE&PID_0010
>      %XYZ% = XYZ_Install,USB\VID_16DE&PID_0012
>
> [XYZ_Install.NT] 
>      include = mdmcpq.inf 
>      CopyFiles = FakeModemCopyFileSection 
>      AddReg = All, NULL_MODEMReg, 115200, SERIAL
>
> [XYZ_Install.NT.Services]
>      include = mdmcpq.inf 
>      AddService = usbser, 0x00000000, LowerFilter_Service_Inst
>
> [XYZ_Install.NT.HW]
>     include = mdmcpq.inf 
>      AddReg = LowerFilterAddReg
>
> [All]
>      HKR,,PortSubClass,1,02
>      HKR,,ConfigDialog,,modemui.dll
>     HKR,,EnumPropPages,,"modemui.dll,EnumPropPages"
>
> [NULL_MODEMReg] ; Null-Modem
>      HKR, Init, 1,, "None"
>      HKR, Init, 2,, "NoResponse"
>      HKR, Monitor, 1,, "None"
>      HKR, Answer, 1,, "CLIENTSERVER"
>      HKR, Answer, 2,, "NoResponse"
>      HKR, Settings, DialPrefix,, "CLIENT"
>      HKR,, Properties, 1, 00,00,00,00, 00,00,00,00, 00,00,00,00, 00,00,00,00, 00,00,00,00, 
>      30,00,00,00, 00,c2,01,00, 00,c2,01,00
>      HKR, Responses, "CLIENT",       1, 08, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00,00,00,00 ; Server side - 
>      the client is requesting a connection
>      HKR, Responses, "CLIENT",  1, 08, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00,00,00,00 ; Server side - 
>      the client is requesting a connection
>      HKR, Responses, "CLIENTSERVER", 1, 02, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00,00,00,00 ; Client side - 
>      the server has acknowledged and the connection is completed
>
> [115200]
>      HKR,, DCB, 1, 1C,00,00,00, 00,c2,01,00, 15,20,00,00, 00,00, 0a,00, 0a,00, 08, 00, 00, 
>      11, 13, 00, 00, 00
>
> [SERIAL]
>      HKR,, DeviceType, 1, 00
>
> [Strings]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and after plenty of days i figured out that it is because of USB selective suspend setting.
Just run command prompt and use the following registry command to disable this feature:

```
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Usb /v DisableSelectiveSuspend /t REG_DWORD  /d 1 /f
```